# Convert list to a class

Tags: c#

I have  classes as below

```
public class ClassA
{

   public int Id { get; set;}

}

public class ClassB : List<ClassA>
{

}
```

How do I convert List to ClassB?

I am doing simple casting as below but throws exception.

```
var list1=  new List<ClassA>();

var list2=  (ClassB)list1;
```

regards,
Alan

Comment: You can't cast it like that. Just because a Strawberry is a Fruit, doesn't make every Fruit a Strawberry.

Answer (score 2):

expose a constructor to create instance of ClassB from List

```
public class ClassB : List<ClassA>
{
    public ClassB(IList<ClassA> source) : base(source)
    {
    }
}
```

then use

```
var list1 = new List<ClassA>();
var list2 = new ClassB(list1);
```

you can also expose an explicit operator to make your casting possible:

```
public static explicit operator ClassB(List<ClassA> source)
{
    return new ClassB(source);
}
```

but you can't create conversions from a base class, so you must use composition instead of inheritance, like for example:

```
public class ClassB : IEnumerable<ClassA>
{
    private IList<ClassA> _source;

    public ClassB(IList<ClassA> source)
    {
        _source = source;
    }

    public IEnumerator<ClassA> GetEnumerator() => _source.GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => _source.GetEnumerator();

    public static explicit operator ClassB(List<ClassA> source)
    {
        return new ClassB(source);
    }
}
```

now it's possible to do:

```
var list1 = new List<ClassA>();
var list2 = (ClassB)list1;
```

by replacing `explicit` with `implicit` you can even skip the `ClassB` explicit casting but please try to not use conversion operators at all because too much magic is involved and unless you're the only developer in the project - it may confuse others

Comment: may it called boxing?

Comment: @Deadooshka This is not boxing since the source and the target are both reference types.

Answer (score 0):

no,you can't.
parent class object cannot be converted to sub class

```
var list1=  new List<ClassA>();

var list2=  (ClassB)list1;
```

it can be simplified to below code

```
List<ClassA> list2 = new ClassB();
```